# Can a postgres function run alone without needing the client side to wait for a result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that postgreSQL locks a row while he is doing a function because of transaction process. So I tried to trigger a function when the last row of the table was unlock.

Let's take an example:

function_one() and function_two are defined inside PG.

My application use function_one() to add data or update some stuff whatever. When it's done, the last row needed is unlock and I can do an launch an other transaction if I want. So at this point I want postgreSQL to launch function_two() when function_one() is done.

Thanks for answer(s).

**EDIT : More informations**

I have already tried to put a trigger on a PG catalog but it did not work because I had the information I needed thanks to a view and you can't trigger data of a view.

Comment: It is not true that Postgres "locks" the table while "doing a function". The table will only be locked if you have an explicit `lock table` inside that function.

Comment: Ok sorry I mean he locked it because I'm doing some operations on the table and it add a lock for this operation.

Comment: The (full) table will only be locked if you explicitely use `lock table`. Otherwise only the rows that you update/insert/delete will be locked

Comment: Sure it does not lock all the table just add a lock for the row I'm working on. I just tried to use it because I thought about that solution but it seams to be the bad one...

Comment: You might be looking for an [AFTER INSERT trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html). The docs include example code that you might be able to adapt to your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the link. AFTER INSERT will execute trigger after inserting one row but I have a lot of operation to do before that's why I want the second function to be launch after the first one finish all that it has to do.

Comment: So why not have function one call function two at the end?

Comment: I've tried it but because the first one is call by a PHP script I didn't want him to wait all PG executions to continue execution of the script.

Comment: I just wanted to know if an alternative solution was possible. I know it's kind of tricky but it was to perform some automatic backup between schema. I'll may keep your solution because it seems not possible.

Comment: Does it mean that your question should be: _"Can a postgres function run alone without needing the client side to wait for a result?"_

Comment: I think you right it is better toj turn it like this. Do you know how? I'll try to edit the question. Thanks for it.

Comment: @DavidLevel You can try to use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` in your functions. The first function can `NOTIFY` someone who is listening for the event and will laung the secong function.

Comment: I took a look at this two function and that seems perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So to release a lock you need to do one of the following commands:

```
commit;
rollback;
```

So if you had some code like so:

```
function_one();
commit;    
function_two();
```

That would be what you are looking for.  Essentially the issue is chaining your functions in such a way that you dictate when the lock gets released.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language, you may want to use whatever async API is available.  Such is available in PHP, Perl, and many other languages, but that is a client-side problem, not a server problem.

In essence it is up to the *client* to decide to wait or not for the function to return.